# Running the same script multiple times , easier way to manage and report

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, cron, bots

I'm going to have to run the same python script multiple of times (>500) at the same time using cron, I'm looking for ways to best handle this to avoid problems in future and if there is any better way that I can use for reporting and logging to alert me if one script is down , please advise me with it.

Plan so far, is to make a copy of the same scripts (folder) a couple of times while renaming each to unique name to distinguish later, then run it using cron scheduler.

advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiprocessing if you do not want the data between the processes to be shared. You can give a name to your processes.